# set NULL on struct address passed as value

Tags: c, pointers

I have a struct list that i pass to a function that needs to free the content and the list item (`*l`).

I already free the content with del function but the `*lst` does not get freed.

```c
typedef struct s_list
{
    void            *content;
    struct s_list   *next;
} t_list;

void lstdel_f(void *d)
{
    free(d);
}

void ft_lstdel(t_list *lst, void (*del)(void *))
{
    (*del)(lst->content);
    free(lst);
}

int main()
{
    //this line creates a new list
    t_list *l = ft_lstnew(ft_strdup("test"));

    ft_lstdel(l, &lstdel_f);
    printf("C=%s\n", l->content);

    if (l != NULL)
        puts("still here"); // shouldn't get here
    else
        puts("GOOD"); // should get here
}
```

I cannot use double pointer in the arguments of the function `ft_lstdel`.

Is there anyway to set `NULL` on the list so that the program prints "GOOD"?

EDIT: i removed the cast of t_list **

Comment: Could you *please* better format your code. It's hard to read.

Comment: `&(*lst)` is nonsense. `&(*lst)`is exactly equal to `&*lst` which is exactly `lst`. You don't need to dereference a function pointer, thus you can write `del(&(*lst->content));` but then again `&(*lst->content)` is equal to `&*lst->content` which is `lst->content`. All this throwing in casts and useless operator pairs is just going to make it harder to reason about the code.

Comment: when i do lst->content it does not free the content, but this code del(&(*lst->content)); does

Comment: @Zouheirlin that would probably be because what you're doing is undefined behavior since you casted a `t_list *` to a `t_list **`, which is very wrong.

Comment: okay i removed, i was just testing with it mb

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot use double pointer in the arguments of the function ft_lstdel.
>
> Is there anyway to set null on the list

Nope, there isn't. Not from inside your `ft_lstdel()` function. If you want to modify the value of `l` from inside `ft_lstdel()`, the only way is to pass a pointer to it to. Other than that, you could set it to `NULL` inside `main()` after calling `ft_lstdel()`.

<s>What you're currently doing is wrong, you cannot just cast a `t_list *` to a `t_list **` and expect it to work. You're also doing a lot of unnecessary pointer operations.</s> OP edited the question.

You're not freeing the entire list either. In the general case, you would need a cycle that scans all the `next` elements of the list and frees the entire list, while you're freeing just a single element.

Removing the unnecessary, the only thing that your function should do is this:

```
void ft_lstdel(t_list *lst, void (*del)(void *))
{
    del(lst->content);
    free(lst);
}
```

Note that this still is not ok since you're only freeing one element when you should free *all* of them.

And if you want it to set `l` to `NULL`, then you **have** to pass a pointer to it. **There is no other way**.

```
void ft_lstdel(t_list **lst_ptr, void (*del)(void *))
{
    t_list *lst = *lst_ptr;
    del(lst->content);
    free(lst);
    *lst_ptr = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Yes i understand what you said, but that is my problem, we cannot use double pointers, but this line here (*del)(&(*lst->content)); frees the content but i cannot find a way to set null in the list.

Comment: @Zouheirlin I don't know how to say it more clearly. As I already stated it in my answer twice: **you cannot** do that without using double pointers.

Comment: but they said it is possible and i cannot validate my cursus without it xD (without double pointers)

Comment: @Zouheirlin if they said it's possible then they are wrong. Or maybe you misunderstood what they were asking (this is probably the case). There is no way to let a function modify a value without passing a pointer to it. Either you use a double pointer or you set `l = NULL` inside `main()` after calling your function. What you're asking for is impossible.

Comment: they said that passed an address in here : ft_lstdel not a value, so maybe i should convert it ?

Comment: Also i should only send the function ft_lstdel to them so it should do the work and set it to null, if not it does not work

Comment: @Zouheirlin what you're saying is very unclear. If you have a clear problem statement then I would suggest you to go ahead and add it to your question. Don't spread pieces of information around in comments. `l` is a value indeed. In C you can only pass values to functions. If they said you should "pass an address" then it means you should pass the address of  `l`, which means using double pointers.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. `l` is passed by value so ft_lstnew cannot change the caller's copy.
Without double pointer you'll have to do it manually:

```
ft_lstdel(l, &lstdel_f);
l = NULL;
```

Comment: It should be set inside the function not after it